# How to use (String[] args) in octave as a valid argument

Tags: java, octave

I've been trying to use a command line argument in octave as written in java but I'm not getting success in it. Any help would be highly appreciated???

**Code in Java**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Run mainRun = new Run();
    mainRun.experiment(args);
    System.exit(0);
}
```

**Code in Octave:**

```
enter code here

javaaddpath("Path/bin/GEVA.jar");

global argv;

function GEVARuns();
octave_args=argv;
oct_args_length=size(octave_args);
argc=javaArray('Main.Run', oct_args_length);

for i=1:oct_args_length
  if(i<oct_args_length)
    argc(i) = octave_args{i};
  endif
endfor
endfunction
mainrun = javaObject("Main.Run");
mainrun.experiment(argv);
```

**This is the Error I'm getting in Octave**

```
GEVARun3
Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException at 
Main.AbstractRun.commandLineArgs(AbstractRun.java:418)
at Main.Run.experiment(Run.java:50)
```

Comment: Please describe what you are trying to do. You want to write an executable Octave script which takes arguments and pass these to a java program? What is your goal? Please also read the relevant page on the manual: https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Command-Line-Options.html#Command-Line-Options

Comment: @Andy. Yes, Indeed.

Comment: @Andy. This is the Java Command Line Argument "java -jar GEVA.jar -main_class Main.Run". But I'm trying to pass the same argument in Octave. But, I am not sure how to use it.

Comment: You can't just build up exactly that string in octave and call the command using `system()` ?

Comment: @NickJ That's not a string. Please avoid Double Quotes around that Command Line Argument. Thanks

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to do. Have you read about the XY-Problem? If not it's worth to [read and understand it](http://xyproblem.info/) Why are you saying that this (what Nick J has just posted) is not a string? Using `system ()` perhaps does what you want to do

Comment: @Andy, I want to know that we use String[] args in java as an Array of String. But how can I use it in Octave. Thanks

Comment: @Andy Actually, I am trying to run this Java Based GEVA package [in the link below] in octave by accessing its jar file in Bin folder and running the main class. But get an error. [link] (http://ncra.ucd.ie/geva/GEVA-v2.0.zip)

Comment: @ken, was your response to me above an error message that you received? Otherwise I'm not sure what you're trying to tell me since I didn't double quote anything. Assuming the former, did you try single quotes?